# The standard AES_CTR example of CryptoPP runs in ubuntu 20.04 fails

Tags: c++, linux, aes, crypto++

This is a standar AES-CTR example given in Crypto++'s official website
https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

```
// g++ -g3 -ggdb -O0 -DDEBUG -I/usr/include/cryptopp Driver.cpp -o Driver.exe -lcryptopp -lpthread
// g++ -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/cryptopp Driver.cpp -o Driver.exe -lcryptopp -lpthread

#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <cstdlib>
using std::exit;

#include <cryptopp/cryptlib.h>
using CryptoPP::Exception;

#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;

#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
using CryptoPP::StringSink;
using CryptoPP::StringSource;
using CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter;

#include <cryptopp/hex.h>
using CryptoPP::AES;

#include <cryptopp/ccm.h>
using CryptoPP::CTR_Mode;

#include "assert.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    CryptoPP::byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));

    CryptoPP::byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));

    string plain = "CTR Mode Test";
    string cipher, encoded, recovered;

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    // Pretty print key
    encoded.clear();
    StringSource(key, sizeof(key), true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "key: " << encoded << endl;

    // Pretty print iv
    encoded.clear();
    StringSource(iv, sizeof(iv), true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "iv: " << encoded << endl;

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    try
    {
        cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

        CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        cout << "after definition1" << endl;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);
        cout << "after definition2" << endl;

        // The StreamTransformationFilter adds padding
        //  as required. ECB and CBC Mode must be padded
        //  to the block size of the cipher.
        StringSource(plain, true, 
            new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipher)
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter      
        ); // StringSource
    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    // Pretty print
    encoded.clear();
    StringSource(cipher, true,
        new HexEncoder(
            new StringSink(encoded)
        ) // HexEncoder
    ); // StringSource
    cout << "cipher text: " << encoded << endl;

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    try
    {
        CTR_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
        d.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
        //  padding as required.
        StringSource s(cipher, true, 
            new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                new StringSink(recovered)
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter
        ); // StringSource

        cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << endl;
    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on my ubuntu 20.04 system, the line `CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;` has an error tips **segment fault**.

Since this is the standard example, I don't know how to solve this error.

Moreover, this example runs well in Win 11.

So, is it blame to linux?

Please tell me how to fix this problem. Thank you.

I want to solve this bug, I don't want to change to Win 11 to run this code.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs for me. How did you install crypto++? My guess would be you're compiling and running against different versions

Comment: I use crypto++ 8.6 (the newest version) with the linux command `sudo apt install libcrypto++-dev`, do you run this example in ubuntu20.04, can you share your version of crypto++ with me? thank you very much.

Comment: I just used the version from apt too

Comment: It doesn't work for me, still thank you.

Comment: Finally,  I give up the AES_CTR, and try to use AES_CBC, it works. Don't know why, but kind of solution.